# Deploying GitHub project to Dokku system

Tags: git, github, web-deployment, dokku

I know you can deploy your project to dokku with a GitHub workflow. But I have seen that there is also the function dokku `git:sync`, so dokku should capture changes on the master branch and download the new version or? But I always get a permission denied error, which ssh key do I have to enter where?

Answer (score 0):

The [dokku page](https://dokku.com/docs/deployment/methods/git/#initializing-from-private-repositories) mentions:

> Initializing from a private repository requires one of the following:
>
> A Public SSH Key (`id_rsa.pub` file) configured on the remote server, with the associated private key (`id_rsa`) in the Dokku server's `/home/dokku/.ssh/` directory.

And:

> In order to clone a remote repository, the remote server should have the Dokku host's public key configured.
> This plugin does not currently create this key, but if there is one available, it can be shown via the `git:public-key` command.
>
> ```
> dokku git:public-key
> ```
>
> If there is no key, an error message is shown that displays the command that can be run on the Dokku server to generate a new public/private ssh key pair.

Comment: The problem is when I create a key via the command it is not listed at dokku git:public-key

Comment: @Cova-1 That means the public key was not set up, as mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/dokku/dokku/issues/4364#issuecomment-773164499).